# Ajax Call from React to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I am trying to make an ajax call from my react component to a php file in which I am expecting the php file to return a specific output but instead I get an entire source code. Can someone help?

This is what I have on my react component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';


export default class BikePage extends React.Component {
    onFormSubmitSuccess(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'php/new_user.php',
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('success')
        console.log(data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.log('error')
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onFormSubmitSuccess.bind(this)} >click here</button>
    )
  }
}
```

This is whats on my php file.

```
<?php
//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
$return = 'hello'
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

All I am trying to test is to get the "Hello" on my console. but instead I get the entire php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you are using `json_encode()` in PHP for getting response, and not using `DataType:json`, you just need to use DataType as json like:

```
dataType: "json",
```

Your json output should be looks like: `"message"`

**Modified Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
url: 'php/new_user.php',
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(data); // will print "message"
}.bind(this),
error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.log('error');
}.bind(this)
});
```

Comment: I simply added datatype json and now i get an error. I console log the status, err and xhr and it does not responde with anything.  The xhr response with an object and its a status 200 with a response text **<?PHP↵$data = 'hello'↵header('Content-Type: application/json');↵echo json_encode($data);↵?> .** The status is **Syntax error unexpected tocken < in JSON** and the err message is **parseerror**

Comment: @BrianBier: why are u using `header('Content-Type: application/json');`?

Comment: I was just testing to see if that was the problem. but its not.

Comment: @BrianBier: chk browser console

Comment: Those error messages are coming from the browser console. Is there a way around it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all 'hello' is not json encodable you need to use for example array('result' => 'hello').

If you gets php file's content it seems that you don't use working local server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `header` in your `PHP` to send JSON results

Try this

```
<?PHP
$data = 'hello'
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```